# How can I reset a setTimeout loop on an API server response

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, api, loops

I am currently trying to create my own "smart light" controller from the ease of an html document. For testing purposes, I have created the following.

An HTML document where when a button is clicked, an API POST request is sent to my localhost API server (running node.js) carrying Information regarding 3 colors which will eventually be cycled around. Then, the locally hosted server will receive the information, and begin a looped sequence of the colors I chose. The lighting and information delivery all works as expected, but I have run into two issues I did not plan a solution for.

1. What happens if a button is pressed multiple times (how would the current loop be stopped)
2. How can I set the duration of the cycle, and/or how many times it should cycle.

Although I could probably fix the second problem by creating a value that increments on each loop, and at one point must not be greater than a number chosen specifically per POST request (and then will quit the loop there), no matter what I try, I cannot seem to find a way to stop the entire loop from overlapping with itself and causing a very scary light show experience.

Is there any standard or reasonable way for me to stop running the loop (or completely re-design it), and then run the updated version right after? I would greatly appreciate the help.

**Server Code (runs when a POST request is sent to the valid URL)**

```
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
    song = (req.body.song)
    color1 = parseInt(req.body.color1);
    color2 = parseInt(req.body.color2);
    color3 = parseInt(req.body.color3);

    light2.power(true, 600, { hue: color1, saturation: 100, color_temp: 0, brightness: 0 });
    light.power(true, 600, { hue: color1, saturation: 100, color_temp: 0, brightness: 0 });

   

    function colors() {

        setTimeout(function () {


            // Part 1
            light2.power(true, 1500, { hue: color1, saturation: 100, color_temp: 0, brightness: 100 });
            light.power(true, 600, { hue: color1, saturation: 100, color_temp: 0, brightness: 100 });
            console.log(color1)

            //Part 2
            setTimeout(function () {
                light2.power(true, 1500, { hue: color2, saturation: 100, color_temp: 0, brightness: 100 });
                light.power(true, 1500, { hue: color2, saturation: 100, color_temp: 0, brightness: 100 });
                console.log(color2)
            }, 2000);

            //Part 3
            setTimeout(function () {
                light2.power(true, 1500, { hue: color3, saturation: 100, color_temp: 0, brightness: 100 });
                light.power(true, 1500, { hue: color3, saturation: 100, color_temp: 0, brightness: 100 });
                console.log(color3)
            }, 4000);
            colors();
        }, 6150);
    }

   setTimeout(function(){
        colors();
   }, 1000);



    console.log(req.body);
    res.send(req.body);

    
});
```

**Client Code (runs when a user presses "play")**

```
            var songChoice = "";
            var color1Choice = "";
            var color2Choice = "";
            var color3Choice = "";
            var songURL = "";
            var currentAudio = "";

            function Selected(songOBJ, songPicked, color1Assigned, color2Assigned, color3Assigned) {
                songChoice = songPicked;
                color1Choice = color1Assigned;
                color2Choice = color2Assigned;
                color3Choice = color3Assigned;
                console.log(currentAudio.length)

                if (currentAudio.duration > 1) {
                    currentAudio.pause();
                }
            
                songURL = songOBJ.getAttribute("data-song")
                currentAudio = new Audio("Content/Songs/" + songURL);
                currentAudio.play();
                
            }
        $(document).ready(function() {


            $('.Play').click(function() {
                $('.Play').toggleClass('Play-Active');
    
                var musicData = {
                    song: songChoice, 
                    color1: color1Choice, 
                    color2: color2Choice, 
                    color3: color3Choice,
                };
    
                $.ajax({
                    url : (server URL),
                    type: "POST",
                    data : musicData,
                    async : true,
                    success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        console.log(response);
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log(jqXHR);
                        console.log(textStatus);
                        console.log(errorThrown);
                    }
                });
            })
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

To stop a timeout you started you use the "interval" that is returned from `setTimeout`, along with the `clearTimeout` function, like so:

```
const timeout = setTimeout(doSomething, 5000);
clearTimeout(timeout); // cancel the timeout
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to clear a timeout you can do it like this:

```
const timeoutID = setTimeout(function () {
                light2.power(true, 1500, { hue: color2, saturation: 100, color_temp: 0, brightness: 100 });
                light.power(true, 1500, { hue: color2, saturation: 100, color_temp: 0, brightness: 100 });
                console.log(color2)
            }, 2000);

clearTimeout(timeoutID);
```